# Polar and Cartesian calculations not completely working?

Tags: .net, trigonometry, cartesian

```
double testx, testy, testdeg, testrad, endx, endy;

testx = 1;
testy = 1;
testdeg = atan2( testx, testy) / Math::PI* 180;  
testrad = sqrt(pow(testx,2) + pow(testy,2));
endx = testrad * cos(testdeg);
endy = testrad * sin(testdeg);
```

All parts of this seem to equate properly, 
except endx and endy should = testx and testy
they do when calculating by hand.

Comment: Can you add the values you are seeing.

Comment: Are your parameters backwards for atan2?

Comment: @mbeckish - good point, however it doesn't matter in this case as both values are 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see two possible problems here:

- `atan2` takes the parameters in order (y,x) in every language I'm aware of. You passed in (x,y).
- `cos` and `sin` take parameters in radians, but you're giving them in degrees. Remove the multiplication by 180/pi to keep the angle in radians.

Comment: Ahh wow, i WAS inputting degs into cos/sin not RADS. thank you